# Group similar nodes in a view

Tags: nodes, views

I have a group of universities that have a director.  However, BYU has 2 directors.  I try and "group multiple values" and turn on distinct in the "basic settings", but then fields for only one director appear while both director names appear.

Basically I want the same layout as below, but Tracy and Carl to be on the same row with their contact information.

I've tried for a few hours and googled for another few hours... Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/awWQ4.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdFxS.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that might have a similar issue (having one node with 2 relationships and all other nodes in the view have 1 relationship to display) I found that by displaying the node teaser instead of just the field, I can get the information I need.